# SSIS parallel Execute Package Tasks vs C# For.Parallel

Tags: c#, performance, ssis, parallel-processing

After searching and trying and testing for quite some time now, I Need to ask a question - maybe someone here can help me.

In a project I am currently working on, I need to process a huge number of XML files (up to 28k files, each with up to 30MB). These files have to be loaded to a SQL DB (a corresponding SSIS component is used for transformation). Since sequentially processing this amount of files would take a very Long time, I decided to go for parallel execution.

My **first design** featured a task to pre-process the files (evaluate the number of files and amount of data and distribute them to 14 list variables in order to be processed by 14 cores) and then execute the child package in 14 separate Execute Package Tasks (in-process; MaxConcurrent set to -1). This works, but the Performance is quite poor and strangely enough, the resource monitor only shows a CPU usage between 30% and 50%.

In my **second design** I created a C# script Task, which executes the child package in a For.Parallel Loop via PackageInfo.Execute. While this hugely inreases the performance (and leads to a CPU usage of 75% to 100%), it leads to other risks (deadlocks and so on).

Last but not least, in my **third design** I tried a design found on the web featuring a queue with all filenames in it and 14 workers dequeueing and processing the files - quite slow as well... I guess the overhead is way to high.

Now **my question**: WHY is the Execute Package Task so much slower than the C# call (Design 1 and 2)?

I need to achieve a stable and performant way, to process this amount of data - and from todays Point of view, none of my designs seems to fullfill this task...